# Adding in sequences of hyphens, of a specific length, into sequences using loops

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I have three text files:

```
>xx_oneFish |xxx
AAAAAAA
>xx_twoFish |xxx
CCCCCC
>xx_redFish |xxx
TTTTTT
>xx_blueFish |xxx
GGGGGG
```

```
>xx_oneFish |xxx
aaaa
>xx_twoFish |xxx
cccc
```

```
>xx_redFish |xxx
tt
>xx_blueFish |xxx
gg
```

I am trying to get an output, where the sequences of letters for each species (redFish, blueFish etc.) are put together in a list, in the same order as they appear in the files in my directory where the sequences are stored. There will be one nested list for each of the species.

If a file contains no sequence for a species, I want to add in a string of hyphens that is the same length as the sequence present in the file for other species.

i.e. for this dataset the output should look like this:

```
[['--', 'aaaa', 'AAAAAAA'], ['--', 'cccc', 'CCCCCC'], [ 'tt', '----', 'TTTTTT'], ['gg', '----', 'GGGGGG']]
```

Here is my current code:

```
differentNames =  ['oneFish', 'twoFish', 'redFish', 'blueFish']
concatSeq = [[], [], [], []]

import os
testSequences = []
testNames = []
for filename in os.listdir("./"): #go to directory where aligned files are kept
    if filename.endswith(".txt"): #open files which have been aligned with MAFFT
        fastaFile = open(filename, 'r') 
        temp_sub_list_names = []
        temp_sub_list_seq = []
        for line in fastaFile:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                if not line.startswith('>'):
                    temp_sub_list_seq.append(line)
                else:
                    temp_sub_list_names.append(line)
        testSequences.append(temp_sub_list_seq)
        testNames.append(temp_sub_list_names)

for i in range(len(testNames)):
    for k in range(len(testNames[i])):
        for j in range(len(differentNames)):
            if differentNames[j] in testNames[i][k]: #check whether the sequence names match up
                concatSeq[j].append(testSequences[i][k]) #if they do, add the sequence to the corresponding list
        c = 1
        for a in range(len(concatSeq)):
        #   for b in range(len(concatSeq[a]):
            if len(concatSeq[a]) < c:
                hyphenString = "-" * len(testSequences[c-1][0])
                concatSeq[a].append(hyphenString)
        c+=1


print concatSeq
```

Something is going wrong in the final loop, as this is my output:

```
[['aaaa', 'AAAAAAA'], ['----', 'cccc', 'CCCCCC'], ['----', 'tt', 'TTTTTT'], ['----', 'gg', 'GGGGGG']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `re` module for parsing the files, you can use this example:

```
file_1 = '''>xx_oneFish |xxx
AAAAAAA
>xx_twoFish |xxx
CCCCCC
>xx_redFish |xxx
TTTTTT
>xx_blueFish |xxx
GGGGGG'''

file_2 = '''>xx_oneFish |xxx
aaaa
>xx_twoFish |xxx
cccc'''

file_3 = '''>xx_redFish |xxx
tt
>xx_blueFish |xxx
gg'''

import re
from collections import OrderedDict

f1 = OrderedDict(re.findall(r'>.*?_(.*?)\s.*?\n(.*?)(?=\n|\Z)', file_1, flags=re.DOTALL))
f2 = OrderedDict(re.findall(r'>.*?_(.*?)\s.*?\n(.*?)(?=\n|\Z)', file_2, flags=re.DOTALL))
f3 = OrderedDict(re.findall(r'>.*?_(.*?)\s.*?\n(.*?)(?=\n|\Z)', file_3, flags=re.DOTALL))

differentNames = {'oneFish', 'twoFish', 'redFish', 'blueFish'}

d = OrderedDict()
for i, f in enumerate([f1, f2, f3]):
    for k, v in f.items():
        if k in differentNames: # <-- comment this out if you want to check for all species in files
            d.setdefault(k, []).append((i, v))

lengths = dict(i for v in d.values() for i in v)

vals = []
for k, v in d.items():
    dd = dict(v)
    vals.append([dd.get(i, '-' * len(lengths[i])) for i in range(len(lengths))][::-1])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(vals)
```

Prints:

```
[['--', 'aaaa', 'AAAAAAA'],
 ['--', 'cccc', 'CCCCCC'],
 ['tt', '----', 'TTTTTT'],
 ['gg', '----', 'GGGGGG']]
```

Comment: I would prefer not to import other modules and just edit what I have already in this case, but thank you