# python script not joining strings as expected

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I have a list of lists of sequences, and a corresponding list of lists of names.

```
testSequences = [
    ['aaaa', 'cccc'],
    ['tt', 'gg'],
    ['AAAAAAA', 'CCCCCC', 'TTTTTT', 'GGGGGG']]
testNames = [
    ['>xx_oneFish |xzx', '>xx_twoFish |zzx'],
    ['>xx_redFish |zxx', '>xx_blueFish |zxx'],
    ['>xx_oneFish |xzx', '>xx_twoFish |xzx', '>xz_redFish |xxx', '>zx_blueFish |xzz']]
```

I also have a list of all the identifying parts of the names:

```
taxonNames = ['oneFish', 'twoFish', 'redFish', 'blueFish']
```

I am trying to produce a new list, where each item in the list will correspond to one of the "identifying parts of the names", and the string will be made up of all the sequences for that name.

If a name and sequence does not appear in one of the lists in the lists (i.e. no `redFish` or `blueFish` in the first list of `testNames`) I want to add in a string of hyphens the same length as the sequences in that list. This would give me this output:

```
['aaaa--AAAAAA', 'cccc--CCCCCC', '----ttTTTTTT', '----ggGGGG']
```

I have this piece of code to do this.

```
complete = [''] * len(taxonNames)

for i in range(len(testSequences)):
    for j in range(len(taxonNames)):
        sequenceLength = len(testSequences[i][0])
        for k in range(len(testSequences[i])):
            if taxonNames[j] in testNames[i][k]:
                complete[j].join(testSequences[i][k]) 
            if taxonNames[j] not in testNames[i][k]:
                hyphenString = "-" * sequenceLength
                complete[j].join(hyphenString)

print complete
```

"complete" should give my final output as explained above, but it comes out looking like this:

```
['', '', '', '']
```

How can I fix my code to give me the correct answer?

Comment: the expression `complete[j].join(testSequences[i][k])` returns a *new string*. You do nothing with that string, and it is immediately discarded. Python strings are immutable. This does not affect the `str` object inside `complete[j]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how can I modify my code so that it will give me the correct answer?

Comment: You need to modify *the list*, so `complete[j] = complete[j].join(testSequences[i][k])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga removing the `if not` statement from line 9 and down, and changing line 8 from `complete[j].join(testSequences[i][k])` to `complete[j] = complete[j].join(testSequences[i][k])` gives me this: `['AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaA', 'CccccCccccCccccCccccCccccC', 'TttTttTttTttTttT', 'GggGggGggGggGggG']`

Comment: Why are there two hyphens in `'aaaa--AAAAAA'` but four hyphens in `'----ttTTTTTT'`?

Comment: Also, are you assuming no 'taxonName' will ever appear in two values of a sub-list of `testNames`? For example, if a `taxonName` of `Fish` would be added, it would be in all `testNames`, what would be the expected outcome?

Comment: @Grismar in the first list in `testSequences` the sequences present are 4 letters long. There are no letters for `redFish` or `blueFish`, so I add in 4 hyphens to keep the alignment for the next list of sequences to be added. In the next list in `testSequences` the sequences present are 2 letters long, no letters are present for `oneFish` or `twoFish` so they get two hyphens. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Grismar The `taxonNames` are pre-defined, a `taxonName` of `Fish` would not be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code, which makes it very hard to understand, is you're not really leveraging the language elements that make Python so strong.

Here's a solution to your problem that works:

```
test_sequences = [
    ['aaaa', 'cccc'],
    ['tt', 'gg'],
    ['AAAAAAA', 'CCCCCC', 'TTTTTT', 'GGGGGG']]
test_names = [
    ['>xx_oneFish |xzx', '>xx_twoFish |zzx'],
    ['>xx_redFish |zxx', '>xx_blueFish |zxx'],
    ['>xx_oneFish |xzx', '>xx_twoFish |xzx', '>xz_redFish |xxx', '>zx_blueFish |xzz']]

taxon_names = ['oneFish', 'twoFish', 'redFish', 'blueFish']


def get_seqs(taxon_name, sequences_list, names_list):
    for seqs, names in zip(sequences_list, names_list):
        found_seq = None
        for seq, name in zip(seqs, names):
            if taxon_name in name:
                found_seq = seq
                break
        yield found_seq if found_seq else '-' * len(seqs[0])


result = [''.join(get_seqs(taxon_name, test_sequences, test_names)) 
          for taxon_name in taxon_names]

print(result)
```

The generator `get_seqs` pairs up lists from `test_sequences` and `test_names` and for each pair, tries to find the sequence (`seq`) for the name (`name`) that matches and yields it, or yields a string of the right number of hyphens for that list of sequences.

The generator (a function that yields multiple values) has code that quite literally follows the explanation above.

The result is then simply a matter of, for each `taxon_name`, getting all the resulting sequences that match in order and joining them together into a string, which is the `result = ...` line.

You could make it work with list indexing loops and string concatenation, but this is not a PHP question, now is it? :)

Note: for brevity, you could just access the global `test_sequences` and `test_names` instead of passing them in as parameters, but I think that would come back to haunt you if you were to actually use this code. Also, I think it makes semantic sense to change the order of names and sequences in the entire example, but I didn't to avoid further deviating from your example.

Comment: Thanks, I think part fo the problem is that I have a basic knowledge of python, so have not covered much beyond list indexing loops and string concatenation yet

Comment: Yeah, that's alright, I tried fixing your code first, but there were so many changes needed I figured I'd better just share a nice example of how you can do this in Python

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that may do what you want. It begins, not with your data structures from this post, but with the three example files from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097190/adding-in-sequences-of-hyphens-of-a-specific-length-into-sequences-using-loops) (which you used to build this post's data structures).

The only thing I couldn't figure out was how many hyphens to use for a missing sequence from a file.

```
differentNames = ['oneFish', 'twoFish', 'redFish', 'blueFish']
files = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']

data = [[] for _ in range(len(differentNames))]
final = []

for file in files:
    d = dict()
    with open(file, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line.startswith('>'): # for ex., >xx_oneFish |xxx
                underscore = line.index('_')
                space = line.index(' ')
                key = line[underscore+1:space]
            else:
                d[key] = line

    for i, key in enumerate(differentNames):
        data[i].append(d.get(key, '-' * 4))

for array in data:
    final.append(''.join(array))

print(final)
```

Prints:

```
['AAAAAAAaaaa----', 'CCCCCCcccc----', 'TTTTTT----tt', 'GGGGGG----gg']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The number of hyphens added is the number needed to make all sequences the same length (in this case 12 characters). in the first list in `testSequences` the sequences present are 4 letters long. There are no letters for `redFish` or `blueFish`, so I add in 4 hyphens to keep the alignment for the next list of sequences to be added. In the next list in `testSequences` the sequences present are 2 letters long, no letters are present for `oneFish` or `twoFish` so they get two hyphens. Hope this clarifies.